# How to solve alike "linking CXX executable" issues

Tags: compiling, cmake, clang, dlna, gerbera

My attempts to compile to get [Gerbera](https://github.com/gerbera/gerbera), a popular DLNA server running proved futile. The dependencies seem to be alright. The documentation doesn't mention any make flags needed. So when I try to make, building reaches 100% and then fails on

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable gerbera
```

with the following message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: liblibgerbera.a(sqlite_database.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'sqlite3_mprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gerbera.dir/build.make:98: gerbera] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/gerbera.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I am unfamiliar with this kind of issue, so would be grateful if someone explained it to me or, if possible, helped me to fix it

Comment: `DSO missing from command line` usually means there should have been a directive like `-lsqlite3` in the link command. Did you install all the recommended prerequisites including `libsqlite3-dev`?

Comment: Yes, the documentation has the list of all recommended prerequisites. I have no issues with that.

Comment: Where is this link command stored?

Comment: It should be part of the Makefile (or a subsidiary Makefile) that is generated by the cmake command

Comment: What operating system and version are you using?

Comment: xubuntu 20.04  Sandy Bridge CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried building from the standard instructions and also found problems. However I did manage to build it in the end as follows:

### Install Dependencies

```
sudo apt install uuid-dev libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmagic-dev libexif-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libspdlog-dev libpugixml-dev libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev libavfilter-dev libavresample-dev libswscale-dev libswresample-dev libpostproc-dev duktape-dev libmatroska-dev libsystemd-dev libtag1-dev libfmt-dev ffmpeg git cmake autoconf libtool
```

### Build/Install spdlog

During my first "configure" I received a message stating that there would be a conflict with the Ubuntu provided spdlog. Here we build and install our own with the correct flags set.

```
git clone https://github.com/gabime/spdlog
cd spdlog
cmake -D "SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL:BOOL=true" .
make
sudo make install
```

### Download gerbera

```
git clone https://github.com/gerbera/gerbera.git
```

### Build/Install libupnp

The library provided by Ubuntu is too old so we need to build and install a newer version. The gerbera source provides a script to do this for us.

```
cd gerbera/scripts/
chmod +x install-pupnp.sh
sudo ./install-pupnp.sh
```

### Build/Install gerbera

From the folder holding the gerbera root folder you downloaded:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DWITH_MAGIC=1 -DWITH_MYSQL=1 -DWITH_CURL=1 -DWITH_JS=1 -DWITH_TAGLIB=1 -DWITH_AVCODEC=1 -DWITH_EXIF=1 -DWITH_LASTFM=0 -DWITH_SYSTEMD=1 ../gerbera
make
sudo make install
```

The above all worked when I tried it on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

### Alternative

If you'd rather not build gerbera yourself, there is a Ubuntu PPA available. Therefore, you could install gerbera easily as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stephenczetty/gerbera-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gerbera
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your help. However, I can not find the gerbera.service file on /etc/systemd/system/
Is it critical if I want to run as a daemon? What do I do in this case?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know anything about Gerbera, what it does or how it works. That's an entirely different question.